# aspnetcoremoduleV2 missing from iis modules after running the runtime bundle

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I dont have aspnetcoremoduleV2 in iis modules, even after installing the runtime/hosting bundle

so I cant deploy or test any core service

P.S: I used to have the moduleV2 in iis, but I accidentally deleted some files from C:/inetpub folder (not 100% sure if any files were actually deleted), but since then the module disappeared and all core apps are giving me 
"aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModuleV2" in its module list using IIS"

in folder Systerm32/inetsrv the module is missing, when I tried to add it manually and and it in the app.hosting file the iis (sort of crashed) no app was able to run until I removed these Manuel edits

I tried to re-install iis several time/ reinstall the bundle but had to luck

Comment: Which hosting bundle did you install?

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below command to remove the asp.net core module and try to install it again. Appcmd.exe delete module MODULE_NAME /app.name:APPLICATION_NAME

Comment: @LexiLi I downloaded this one 
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.2.7-windows-hosting-bundle-installer
and tried older versions too (2.2.4 & 2.2.6 & 2.2.2)

Comment: @BrandoZhang after running the command the module was removed from iis modules, then installed 2.2.7 bundle . however the module wasn't added to iis 
(neither aspNetCoreModule nor aspNetCoreModuleV2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following from @brandoZhang's answer & iis docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview#managing-modules-from-the-command-line)

I have done the following and its now working
1- delete the current aspNetCoreModule (I guess this part was unnecessary)
2- install the module manually if it doesnt appear in iis modules after downloading the runtimebundle

- open cmd as admin
- navigate to inetSrv location `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`
- run: `appcmd.exe install module /name:AspNetCoreModule /image:%windir%\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll`
- And same for aspnetcoremoduleV2, but its location is in a different place. Mine was in `%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll`

  - so I ran: `appcmd.exe install module /name:AspNetCoreModuleV2 /image:"%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll"`

if a duplication error appeared, delete the old one and then re install it

Comment: Hi Lino, I followed your step and I saw AspNetCoreModule2 installation successful message. In IIS Modules I can see it in Configure Native Modules, however, in physical path there's not aspnetcorev2.dll installed. I wonder if you can see dll file?

Comment: To elaborate my last comment, I misunderstood the module installation. It turns out the installation is to define the module and the regarding DLL in <globalModules> section of IIS configuration file, for IIS to load the module, rather than installing the DLL into this folder.

Afterwards, if running IIS without having this DLL, you will see 503 Service Unavailable error.

Comment: Hi Lino, I think you typed extra space in the path so it may not be working. Probably the better path should be %ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll which works for me (%ProgramFiles% without any white space)

Answer (score 0):

Following @Lino's Lino answer, I had to uninstall the module (aspnetcorev2 in my case), and repair using dotnet-hosting-xxx installer

Answer (score 0):

In my case AspNetCoreModuleV2 was not detecting in IIS after Hosting bundle installation. But when I tried to install it again with CLI it was there:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe install module /name:AspNetCoreModuleV2 /image:"C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll"
ERROR ( message:Failed to add duplicate collection element "AspNetCoreModuleV2". )
```

In order it to work, i had to delete it first:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>Appcmd.exe uninstall module AspNetCoreModuleV2
Uninstalled MODULE "AspNetCoreModuleV2"
```

And then install it again:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe install module /name:AspNetCoreModuleV2 /image:"C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll"
GLOBAL MODULE object "AspNetCoreModuleV2" added
MODULE object "AspNetCoreModuleV2" added
```